# extracting the data from a column in pandas dataframe using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` as defined below

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "name": [
            "Hello Kitty how=1234 when=2345",
            "how=3456 Hello Puppy when=7685",
            "how=646 It is an Helloexample when=9089",
            "for how=6574 stackoverflow when=5764",
            "Hello  when=3632 World how=7654",
        ],
    }
)





df
Out[100]: 
   ID                                     name
0   1           Hello Kitty how=1234 when=2345
1   2           how=3456 Hello Puppy when=7685
2   3  how=646 It is an Helloexample when=9089
3   4     for how=6574 stackoverflow when=5764
4   5           Hello  when=3632 World how=7654
```

I want to extract the values written that are after `how` and `when` into  two separate columns how and when. How can I do the same using regular expression ?

For example: in first record I should get `1234` in column `how` and `2345` in column `when`. In last record I should get `7654` in column `how` and `3632` in column `when`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `str.extract`

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "name": [
            "Hello Kitty how=1234 when=2345",
            "how=3456 Hello Puppy when=7685",
            "how=646 It is an Helloexample when=9089",
            "for how=6574 stackoverflow when=5764",
            "Hello  when=3632 World how=7654",
        ],
    }
)
df['when'] = df['name'].str.extract(r"when=(\w+)")  #If only int use `(\d+)`
df['how'] = df['name'].str.extract(r"how=(\w+)")    #If only int use `(\d+)`
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   ID                                     name  when   how
0   1           Hello Kitty how=1234 when=2345  2345  1234
1   2           how=3456 Hello Puppy when=7685  7685  3456
2   3  how=646 It is an Helloexample when=9089  9089   646
3   4     for how=6574 stackoverflow when=5764  5764  6574
4   5          Hello  when=3632 World how=7654  3632  7654
```

Comment: and how to extract if the number contains a decimal also like 32.46 or .786 ?

Comment: use `\d*\.?\d*`?

Comment: do you mean like this : df['when'] = df['name'].str.extract(r"when=(\d)|(\d*\.\d*)")

Comment: when I am using `df['when'] = df['name'].str.extract(r"when=(\d*\.\d*)")` it is just extracting the digits with decimals , how can I extract the numbers both with or without decimals ?

Comment: You missed the `?`

Answer (score 0):

Use *df.name.str.extract(...)*.
The first argument in this method is *pattern*.
Include there two named capturing groups, for each fragment to capture.

Something like:

```
df.name.str.extract(r'(?P<how>(?<=how=)[\d.]+)|(?P<when>(?<=when=)[\d.]+)')
```

The pattern should be passed as a *raw string*, due to contained backslashes.

Comment: and how to extract if the number contains a decimal also like 32.46 or .786 ?